# multiprocessing ThreadPool reading and writing files

Tags: python, io, threadpool, python-multithreading

I got over 10000 files that i need to open to and in some of them I need to delete part of the data
tried to do it with threadpool but from the time its taking i dont thinks its works

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def readwrite(file):
    with open(file,'rb') as f:
        #check something
    #if check something is True
    #else return
    with open(new_file,'wb') as f:
        with open(file,'rb') as g:
             #here i write only the lines i need from the first file
pool = ThreadPool(40)
for file in files:
    pool.apply_async(readwrite,(file,))
```

Comment: Read/write operations usually are the bottleneck of any multithread solution, but in your code it seems to be the only operation. With this conditions multithreading turns code into a one single bottleneck if not narrow it.

Comment: When you try it with 20 files and check the modified files are the modified files correct? In other words, does your solution produce the correct output even if *slow*?

Comment: Did you try using `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`??

Comment: how can i be sure that the problem is in the io operation? 
just checked couple of the outputs and they looks correct
and i didnt not tried ThreadPoolExecutor

Answer (score 0):

Look at example from [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html):

```py
pool.apply_async(f, (20,)) # runs in *only* one process
```

As it said, such call uses only one process/thread from pool.

You should try `pool.map()` instead. Here is the example:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def readwrite(filename):
    pass
    # Your code here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        results = p.map(readwrite, filenames)
```

Comment: just to be sure do u mean apply_async only use the same thread from the pool each time?

Comment: Probably not, but I think, using `apply_async` without `.get()` might block pool after 40 calls, `map()` should solve that

Answer (score 0):

you can't do that, if you have over 10,000 files , it means potentially over 10,000  threads , and that's too much for the regular computer to handle in single core, it's better to go over them 1 by 1 if you're about to use threads, you could calculate the time it will take tho and keep a track about how much files did you rewrite , the processing power and computing power is what it is. you could try to maximize that with the `multiprocessing` module if you have several cores on your CPU
 `"The “multi” in multiprocessing refers to the multiple cores in a computer's central processing unit (CPU)"`
, usually its 2 or 4 cores , and you do it like in the example below from [How to use multiprocessing pool.map with multiple arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/how-to-use-multiprocessing-pool-map-with-multiple-arguments)

```py
def multi_run_wrapper(args):
   return add(*args)

def add(x,y):
    return x+y

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    pool = Pool(4)
    results = pool.map(multi_run_wrapper,[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)])
    print results
```

Comment: pool = ThreadPool(40)
doesnt it mean maximum threads will be 40?
and I'm using apply_async cause I don't have list of all the files they are in different folders I'm getting all them all with os.walk 
i can add them to list and then use pool.map(func,files) but why?

Comment: Threadpool means you open at max 40 threads, on the same core. `Thread - multi programs on the same processor`  `Multiprocess - using another processor at the same time`